# Combine children where parent keys are the same in a array of objects

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects with duplicate parent keys:

```
[
    {parent1: {'child_id_1': 'value_child_1'}}
    {parent1: {'child_id_1_1': 'value_child_1_1'}}
    {parent2: {'child_id_2_1': 'value_child_2_1'}}
    {parent2: {'child_id_2_2': 'value_child_2_2'}}
    {parent2: {'child_id_2_3': 'value_child_2_3'}}
    ...
]
```

And I'm looking for this result:

```
[
    {parent1: {'child_id_1': 'value_child_1'}, {'child_id_1_1': 'value_child_1_1'}}
    {parent2: {'child_id_2_1': 'value_child_2_1'}, {'child_id_2_2': 'value_child_2_2'}, {'child_id_2_3': 'value_child_2_3'}}
]
```

I've tried something similar to this below but it only returns one key pair.

```
const unique = Array.from(new Set(filteredViews.map(a => a.id)))
   .map(id => {
       return filteredViews.find(a => a.view_name === id)
})
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your desired result is not a valid Javascript object.

Comment: The variable "filteredViews" is not defined and so is the property "id". Please edit the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```js
const srcArr = [
    {parent1: {'child_id_1': 'value_child_1'}},
    {parent1: {'child_id_1_1': 'value_child_1_1'}},
    {parent2: {'child_id_2_1': 'value_child_2_1'}},
    {parent2: {'child_id_2_2': 'value_child_2_2'}},
    {parent2: {'child_id_2_3': 'value_child_2_3'}},
];

const targetArr = srcArr.reduce((acc, val) => {
  let [key] = Object.keys(val);
  let obj = acc.find(el => key in el);
  if (!obj) acc.push({[key]: [val[key]]});
  else obj[key].push(val[key]);
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(targetArr);
/* result:
[
  {
    "parent1": [
      {
        "child_id_1": "value_child_1"
      },
      {
        "child_id_1_1": "value_child_1_1"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "parent2": [
      {
        "child_id_2_1": "value_child_2_1"
      },
      {
        "child_id_2_2": "value_child_2_2"
      },
      {
        "child_id_2_3": "value_child_2_3"
      }
    ]
  }
]
*/
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your data looks like this:

```
const data = [
  {parent1: {'child_id_1': 'value_child_1'}},
  {parent1: {'child_id_1_1': 'value_child_1_1'}},
  {parent2: {'child_id_2_1': 'value_child_2_1'}},
  {parent2: {'child_id_2_2': 'value_child_2_2'}},
  {parent2: {'child_id_2_3': 'value_child_2_3'}},
]
```

Using a vanilla approach you could do:

```
let unique = {};

data.forEach(d => {
  let key = Object.keys(d)[0]; // assuming your object has a single key
  if (!unique[key]) { unique[key] = []; }
  unique[key].push(d[key]);
});
```

Resulting in:

```
{
  "parent1": [
     {"child_id_1":"value_child_1"}, 
     {"child_id_1_1":"value_child_1_1"}
  ],
  "parent2": [
     {"child_id_2_1":"value_child_2_1"},
     {"child_id_2_2":"value_child_2_2"},
     {"child_id_2_3":"value_child_2_3"}
  ]
}
```

Comment: OP's desired result is an array, yours is an object, but not an array. Also your code would fail in case `data` contains `{parent2: null}`.